# Plugin - Flickr Photo Picker

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

Has anyone used this plugin recently: https://github.com/ObiruLabs/craft-flickr-photopicker ?
I have just tried to start using it but it does not display any photos - it seems to be looking for photo sets but I don't see an option within Flickr for photosets.